# How to get key statistics for yahoo finance web search api?

Tags: yahoo-api, yahoo-finance

I am working on retrieving yahoo finance companies data and I was succeeded in getting the companies stock data. Apart from the basic data I am also trying to retrieve key statistics data for the same company. Below image is the key statistics fields which I require.

[image]

I am using yahoo web service api to get the stock data. But when I am trying to add the parameters like **f=nab** and **f=snbaopl1** , I am getting **406 error response code**. The below is the finance api which I am using.

```
http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/SPARC.BO/quote?format=json&view=detail&f=nab
```

If that is the way to give then how should I get the stocks key statistics for companies.

Comment: Can anyone help me out ? I am trying very hardly and researching in many ways but I didn't found any alternate options. The one which I found were deprecated. Why no one is responding to the yahoo questions

Answer (score 18):

You can try access this link:

https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v10/finance/quoteSummary/YOUR_COMPANY_SYMBOL?modules=ANY_PERMITTED_MODULE_SEPPARATED_BY_COMMAS

i found some modules that i think are interesting:

```
assetProfile
financialData
defaultKeyStatistics
calendarEvents
incomeStatementHistory
cashflowStatementHistory
balanceSheetHistory
```

this link will response with a json file.

Comment: Can this be altered to retrieve a csv file?

Comment: Thankyou!! Thats what I was looking for...
but there are still couple of attributes that I couldn't get which I needed i.e. Price/Sales (ttm), Market Cap (intraday) [very important], Price/Sales (ttm)
Any help regarding these attributes?

Comment: Try with summaryProfile

Comment: @YagoRodriguez Is there any documentation on this API ? I was trying to get an idea of the query parameters.

Comment: just try the parameters and read what they return... is what i did

Comment: @YagoRodriguez This is great. I have to ask though - if there're no docs on it, how did you come up with it? I've been busting my head trying to scrape from the new HTML page with no luck and this really saves the day.

Comment: I'm thinking this won't be available for very long...a year at most maybe.

Comment: Is it possible to get information on the major holders?

Comment: Great list. Also recommendationTrend is a useful module

Comment: @YagoRodriguez how did you identify these modules

Comment: This article references the possible modules https://cryptocointracker.com/yahoo-finance/yahoo-finance-api

Answer (score 2):

I have succeeded in getting yahoo finance key_statistics data by using the following quotes api http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=MSFT&f=snd1l1ydrbj1mt8opjk

By default the api will display the output in csv format if we want we can also convert the CSV output to JSON format.The quotes api is working perfectly fine to my requirement in getting the above mentioned statistics which are given as **f=snd1l1ydrbj1mt8opjk** and also getting the JOSN format by converting the csv output to JSON.

Comment: Still works as of the 20th of March, 2017. Also, great catch!

Comment: What is meant by `f=snd1l1ydrbj1mt8opjk` ? Can you explain what this fields indicate? Thanks.

Comment: s = symbol (i.e., Ticker symbol)
n = company full name
d1 = Last Trade Date
l1 = Last Trade (Price Only)
y = Dividend Yield
d = Dividend / Share   
r = P/E Ratio
b = Bid
j1 = Market Capitalization
m = Day’s Range
t8 = 1yr Target Price
o = Open
p = Previous Close
j = 52-Week Low
k = 52-Week High

Comment: No longer works, now it's saying "It has come to our attention that this service is being used in violation of the Yahoo Terms of Service. As such, the service is being discontinued. For all future markets and equities data research, please refer to finance.yahoo.com."