# How to Download Multiple Stocks Using Yahoo API v11

Tags: finance, yahoo, yahoo-finance, yahoo-api, computational-finance

How can I download multiple symbols using Yahoo Finance API version >= 8? As you can see here I can download multiple stocks with version 7, but from version 8 onwards they changed something:

```
https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/quote?symbols=AAPL,KO
```

Specifically, with the latest version (11) I can add multiple modules with useful data, however I can only use one single stock for each request. How can I download multiple ones as I was able to do in the previous example?

```
https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v11/finance/quoteSummary/KO?modules=summaryProfile,financialData,defaultKeyStatistics
```

I have tried:

```
https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v11/finance/quoteSummary/AAPL,KO?modules=summaryProfile,financialData,defaultKeyStatistics
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/38813354/10126479

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found anything that would indicate that downloading data for multiple tickers is still supported. However, see e.g. [this "Python package whose goal is to fix the support for Yahoo! Finance for Pandas DataReader"](https://github.com/ranaroussi/fix-yahoo-finance/blob/master/fix_yahoo_finance/__init__.py) (credit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49705239/8031521)) which allows you to ask for data on multiple tickers and which then breaks it down into single-ticker requests for you.

Is there a specific reason why you need to retrieve the data on multiple tickers with one request / why using multiple requests is not acceptable?

Comment: Multiple tickers with one request allows me to pull around 9K stocks in a couple of seconds, whereas one ticker per request would take me a time of around 9K seconds by abiding to the usual politness limit of 1 request per second.

Comment: That makes sense but unfortunately I'm not aware of any solution to your problem. Ps. I didn't realize that the "usual politeness limit" was 1 request / second, thanks for pointing that out to me. I had already been using a limit of 2 requests / second because imposing some limit seemed like the right thing to do but will be slowing down my code even further from now on.